# Get context in cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

Hi I'm using [this](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova) GCM notification plugin for android and works almost perfect, the only issue I have is when the user force close my app or when the device is shutted down the notification service stops working.

I've looked the plugin code problem and realized that the following function causes the problem.

```
     public static void sendJavascript( JSONObject _json )
      {
        String _d =  "javascript:"+gECB+"(" + _json.toString() + ")";
            Log.v(ME + ":sendJavascript", _d);

            if (gECB != null ) {
              gwebView.sendJavascript( _d );
            }
}
```

When the device is shutted down and then turned on or the application is force closed, gwebView reference is lost. If I try to use the method gwebView.sendJavascript( _d ) I get a null pointer exception.

Reviewing the plugin code I noticed that gwebView is referenced when registering the device just as this code shows:

```
public static Plugin gwebView;
  private static String gECB;
  private static String gSenderID;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
  public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId)
  {

    PluginResult result = null;

    Log.v(ME + ":execute", "action=" + action);

    if (REGISTER.equals(action)) {

      Log.v(ME + ":execute", "data=" + data.toString());

      try {

        JSONObject jo= new JSONObject(data.toString().substring(1, data.toString().length()-1));

        gwebView = this;

..............................More code here......................
```

The notifications are received on background but I can't invoke any javascript methods since gwebView points nothing.

My approach is to show a generic notification on statusbar whenever gwebView has a null pointer but I just don't know how to get the application or cordova context in order to use this function.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in google forums that this is a bug of the plugin so I decided to use Pushwhoosh notification service.

Comment: Sorry for exhumating, but can you please link that discussion on Google Forums if you remember it?